# How can a Portuguese Graduate work in the USA?

Tags: usa, working-visas, working, business, portugal

I recently finished my 1st year of MSc in Marketing in Portugal and want to move abroad in order to start an international career in the United States as soon as possible. I'm presenting my thesis in September 2017 and I'm planning on working until September 2018, and then move. I've been searching for some internships and graduate programs in Marketing, Digital Marketing, Marketing Agencies and so on, and I know there are a lot of opportunities for locals.

However, I'm feeling a little "scared" because from what I saw there are a lot of obstacles separating me from this goal: is it true that, in order to get a work visa, the employer must go to the immigration services and get it for me? Are you familiar with how to start this process? And how realistic is this goal?

Just wanted to get an idea from someone who already did the jump from Europe to the US :)

Thanks!

Comment: Your goal is realistic, but you need to start planning and acting on it *now*. Check out @mkennedy's link. Since you're doing graduate studies, this kind of research should be know problem for you ;).